# Read a resource file located in external library in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, resources

I have a multi-lingual application, in which all dictionaries are stocked in .resx files, one file for each language.
Until now the dictionary was in my main project, so to read it, I just needed to do

In C# :

```
Properties.Resources.MyKey
```

In XAML :

```
xmlns:p="clr-namespace:VEGA_STEEL.Properties"

Header="{x:Static p:Resources.MyKey}"
```

The main reason why I do so, is to be able to reuse that library in different solutions, so I don't need to translate in each solution if I need to add some fields, or new language.

I have a main class library that I called "MainLibrary"(where I have all the classes that are common to each solution).
I added the properties in that Class Library, all went good, fo C# Just needed to replace all by :

```
MainLibrary.Properties.Resources.MyKey;
```

But in XAML I couldn't find how to set the new reference to the Resources.

I tried just that :

```
xmlns:p="clr-namespace:MainLibrary.Properties"
```

but not working. How can I set a reference to an external library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the assembly name at the end of namespace declaration in xaml. In your case it should be

```
xmlns:p="clr-namespace:MainLibrary.Properties;assembly=MainLibrary"
```

(if your main class library has such name as `MainLibrary`, otherwise use the correct assembly name, not the namespace). You can also have a look at [XAML namespaces mapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/xaml-namespaces-and-namespace-mapping-for-wpf-xaml) for some details